# 2 Particle systems with different curve guide

Tags: particles

I need 2 particles that go in different directions. 1 its ok but the 2 follows the first curve.

Direcction B   Particle   Direcction A

```
             A        Go ----->  Goog

             B        GO ----->  Bad
```

Edit:

This are my particle test

Particles that comes from Sphre have to go throw the left tunel and the right plane throw the right tunel. If they are in the same Layer shpere and plane follows the right curveguide and i need Shpere particles follow left curveguide and plaine follow right curveguide.

It works in different leyers, but I need them in the same layer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Let me see if I got this right, you want two particle systems following different curves? Why not just have a separate object for the second particle system?

Comment: just edited with the pictures I need to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a lattice that serves as a guide for the partices of one object and give it the shape you need:

[image]

Then use that lattice to control the path of the particle system:

[image]

Create a different lattice to use on the second emitter, so that each one of the particle system will flow in different directions.

[image]

Comment: thks cegaton, but it dosent work cus this particles just feld down. Im working on air conditioner that cleans air. and I need that the particles run throw a long pipe system. heres the web page http://www.rr-bethfiltration.de/en/products-overview.html. Now I just made them in different layeres, I just wanted to know how to put them in the same layer cus this way I need 800 layers..... Also I found that If I bake the particles bake them I can move them to the same layer.... work in layer 2 bake and move to layer 1. etc etc... till I have 4 particles sys. baked in layer 1.

Comment: You can use physics to make the particles flow wherever you need them (as it would happen in real life where wind would push them...) The lattices are there just to contain the path and separate the flow for different emitters.